# How to use RootX in basement floor drain without cleanout

Tags: plumbing, drain

I have an older house with a basement floor drain that feeds to a gray water tank (separate from our septic tank).  There is also a drain for our washing machine and a sink that feed into the same pipe.

We had slow/no draining and had a professional come and attempt to auger the pipe but he ran into roots about 70' into the drain and was unable to get it clear.  He suggested using a product like RootX to kill the roots, at least as a short-term solution.

My question is, since RootX foams, is it OK to use in a floor drain that has standing water?  I know it has to be flushed down with gallons of water but the drain is too slow to take that much without backing up.  The washer drain has a several foot tall vertical pipe that may be a better option to use, but I'm still concerned the drain is too slow to get the RootX to the roots.  I could possibly wait a few days to make sure the water is as far down in the pipe as possible but wanted others' opinions before I proceed.